# Read h5 file from remote

Tags: python, ssh

I have a problem, I cannot read h5 file from my server. I have ssh on my server, also server is local. So I have two type of code:

```
store1 = pd.HDFStore(os.system("scp newrow_data_copy.h5 lucy@192.168.1.51:media/lucy/hdd1/hdf_row/Archive1"))
```

Error is Expected bytes, got int. In addition os.system says wrong, expected string

```
store1 = pd.HDFStore('//192.168.1.51/media/lucy/hdd1/hdf_row/Archive1/newrow_data_copy.h5', mode='r')
```

Error: The file doesn't exist. Nevertheless, I see the file on the server.

Whats wrong and what should I do to read h5 file from remote server. I can't download, because the file is huge enough.

Comment: You can check that the file is seen from Python, with `os.path.exists(file)`

Comment: Does `pd.HDFStore()` function expect bytes?

Comment: @GuillaumeJacquenot I did it and there is that file

Comment: @SamChats Yes, it is

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are aware that reading a whole remote file is, by definition, downloading, right? Whether you download the file to your working memory or a disk is a whole different issue.

That being said, both `ssh` and `scp` won't help you much unless you're willing to write your own tty emulator, so instead just install the [`paramiko`](http://www.paramiko.org/) module and use it for all your remote SSH/SFTP needs within Python. In your case, this should do it:

```
import pandas as pd
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()  # start the client
ssh.load_system_host_keys()  # load local host keys
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())  # add the host keys automatically
ssh.connect("192.168.1.51", 22, "lucy", "your_password")  # replace the password with yours

sftp = ssh.open_sftp()  # start a SFTP session
# 'open' the remote file, adjust the path based on your home path (or use an absolute path)
target = sftp.open("media/lucy/hdd1/hdf_row/Archive1/newrow_data_copy.h5")
```

**UPDATE**: But that's how you only get the a remote file handle (which you can stream, seek and do whatever else you would to your local file), sadly on second look - `HDFStore` expects a path to the file and performs all the file handling through `PyTables` so unless you want to hack `PyTables` to work with remote data (and you don't) your best bet is to install [`sshfs`](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs) and mount your remote file system to your local one, and then let Pandas treat the remote files as local ones, something like:

```
sshfs lucy@192.168.1.51:media/lucy/hdd1 ~/hdf
```

And then in Python:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

store1 = pd.HDFStore(os.path.expanduser("~/hdf/hdf_row/Archive1/newrow_data_copy.h5"))
```

The file won't be directly downloaded, unless `PyTables` is instructed to store the file instead of reading it in-memory.

Comment: I need to do sshfs lucy@192.168.1.51:media/lucy/hdd1 ~/hdf in pandas command or Ide?

Comment: @NurislomTuraev - In your console, after installing `sshfs`, before running your Python script. The mount will hold til the next restart, as long as you have a connection to the remote server.

Comment: I found sshfs only in anaconda, pip install doesn't work. When I want to run it in python console, it shows error

Comment: [`sshfs`](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs) is not a python module - it's a SSH File System extension for your OS, so use your OS's package manager to install it. Read the installation instructions on the linked page above, or just do a Google search: `install sshfs <your_operating_system>`

Comment: Everything is good, but it can't read the file. So I just copied it. +1