# How to read HDF5 file in Python/Pandas via SSH?

Tags: pandas, ssh, path, putty, hdf

I'm accessing a remote machine via SSH (Putty). A dataset is stored in a directory on that machine, which I need to read with pandas in Python on my local computer. I am trying to use `dataframe=pandas.read_hdf(path, key="data")` but I don't know which path to specify which would direct towards the dataset stored on the remote machine in my local Python code since it's not stored locally. As I mentioned I am accessing the dataset using Putty.
What should the path look like?
I tried replacing `C:` with the host name followed by the path which I use in Putty to access the file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [Read h5 file from remote](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45144080/850848).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean precisely by read, but you can display the dataframe with the following:

1. SSH to your remote server
2. Navigate to the directory your dataframe is stored in:
   `cd /directory/of/dataframe`
3. Launch a Python or [iPython](https://ipython.org/) interpreter: `python` or `ipython`
4. Execute those python commands:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> dataframe=pandas.read_hdf("hdf_file.h5", key="data")
# This should work because `hdf_file.h5 is 
# in the directory you launched the python command
```

5. Print your dataframe: `print(dataframe)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This seems promising but after launching Python in the shell when I tried importing pandas, I got this error: `"ImportError: No module named pandas"` . Does this mean that pandas is not installed on the host machine? Is there a way I can install it there? On my local laptop I usually use Python 3.7 but in the shell it launches Python 2.7 on the remote machine. Could that be a reason?

Comment: You can try `python3` as a command to launch a python3 interpreter (and see if pandas is installed for python3).
Otherwise you can install pandas with `pip install pandas` or `pip3 install pandas` (please use a [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/))

Comment: Edit:  I tried it with `pip install pandas` which starts collecting pandas but gives me this error: `Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [Errno 2] No such file or directory -- Some packages may not be found!` and `Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-robfndta/pandas`   Also, the host machine is a unix machine, maybe I should have mentioned that earlier. Could you help me install pandas? I don't know what to do about that error

Comment: You have this error because you didn't install it on a `virtualenv`. To install pandas for the user you should do `pip install pandas --user` and it should work.